# rails has_many scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, has-many

1. AppScreenshot

   ```
   class AppScreenshot < ActiveRecord::Base
     include Cacheable
     belongs_to :app

     model_cache do
       with_key
     end

     scope :available , where(["state > ? and is_icon = ? ",0,0])

   end
   ```
2. App:

   ```
   class App < ActiveRecord::Base
     include Cacheable
     #acts_as_cached :ttl => 30.minutes

     has_many :apk_files

     has_many :app_screenshots.available

   end
   ```

why  `has_many :app_screenshots.available` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:app_screenshots is just a Ruby symbol, so you can't call methods on it like that.

I think something like `has_many :app_screenshots, :conditions => 'state > 0 and is_icon = 0'`

should work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

if you execute 1. AppScreenshot and 2. App:, it will throw error message because you can't call this way.